# Win 10 Task View Process

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, task-view

Often times, task view will freeze and hang on one of the two monitors.  Even though I can open task manager in with ctrl+shift+esc or through ctrl+alt+del, I cannot see as it appears to be behind the frozen task view.  It does appear in the task bar and I can use win+right arrow to move it to my other monitor and then use it there.

Task view itself it just completely unresponsive and unless I kill explorer I'm unable to return to my desktop.  Any ideas what could be causing this behavior?  Is task view part of the explorer process or does it have its own?

My system's configuration and installed programs have remained the same for quite a while now.  I'm not sure what could possibly be causing the behavior.

Comment: Explorer.exe is listed.  There are two tabs, are you looking, on the right tab?  Yes; Task View is part of the process

Comment: You really should determine what is causing the behavior.  I have never experienced what you described.

Comment: Yeah I found explorer.exe  listed.  I'm still not really used to the new win 10 format for task manager so I was a bit confused.  as for Task View, I still haven't figured out the issue but I just restart explorer and it seems to be fixed though it does happen again so I usually have to reboot.  I do notice that my memory usage is often at 99% when the PC has been on a bit even though no processes are using much memory.  Also I've noticed UWP apps from the Store tend to have ENORMOUS memory leaks.

Comment: "Also I've noticed UWP apps from the Store tend to have ENORMOUS memory leaks" - Unlikely.  Although you are not very specific.  Likewise Task Manager changed back in 2013 with Windows 8 (or whenever Windows 8 was released)

Comment: Didn't know that about task manager.  But what I meant by that was I often encounter issues with my memory usage when running certain UWP applications.  From my personal experience I encounter the problem most often with apps doing video playback.  For example Netflix, though I've experienced it with a few others as well.

Comment: You might consider using the Reset feature to solve your overall issue.  I have dozens of applications running all the time, task view, never freezes for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, `Task View` is not its own process but a thread within the `Explorer.exe` process, there are usually 70+ threads in Explorer and it would be hard to determine which one is responsible for `Task View`

`Explorer.exe` itself is always listed in the Windows process list, (unless you are running a Windows without Explorer.exe), and killing the explorer.exe process and restarting it may help with your problem.

But it seems something else is wrong with your system.